# "export 'default' (imported as 'Chart') was not found in 'chart.js'

Tags: node.js, vue.js, chartjs

Quando eu dou um `import Chart from 'chart.js'` aparece esse erro no terminal:

```
"export 'default' (imported as 'Chart') was not found in 'chart.js'
```

E esses erros no console:

```
Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: chart_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.default is not a constructor"
TypeError: chart_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.default is not a constructor
```

Estou usando o Vue.js 2 e as versões do Chart.js que dão esse erro são a 3.1.1 e a 3.0.2, a partir da versão 2.9.4 ele funciona normal. Já tentei usar o vue-chartjs mas ele também faz esse mesmo import do Chart.js e acaba resultando no mesmo erro.

Answer (score 1):

Eu estou usando a versão mais atual do ***vue-chartjs*** lançado 22 de Ago de 2020:

```
"vue-chartjs": "^3.5.1",
```

Então todas as versões do Chart.Js (lançadas após 08/2020) não possue compatibilidade.

Para não exibir/ter o erro no console:

```
"export 'default' (imported as 'Chart') was not found in 'chart.js'
```

Utilize a versão ***Chart.Js - 2.9.4*** ou qualquer versão lançada antes de 22 de Ago de 2020:

```
 "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
```

Answer (score 0):

Como o Rogério comentou acima, mudando o chart.js para a versão 2.9.4 o erro desaparece. Pode fazer isso com o comando:

```
npm install chart.js@2.9.4
```

Comment: Agradecimento e considerações do AR feitas no corpo da resposta: *PS: Não respondi nem dei upvote por falta de reputação. Obrigado Rogério pela solução.*

Comment: Giovanni Pizzato, não faça agradecimentos e não coloque assuntos não relacionados tecnicamente a questão nas respostas. Use o campo de comentários.